# Unable to resize despite unallocated chunk with GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

The partition for my Windows used to be much larger, but I've resized it down to 130 GB which yields 70GB. I'm trying to extend the Ubuntu with that chunk, but cannot. I've tried turning the unallocated chunk into a linux-swap and set it "swapon" in hopes of getting it to work the way I want it to, but it didn't.

Edit: First thing that shows up when I power up my laptop is the Lenovo black screen. There are no explanations for function keys. I've tried all keys from F1 to F12 and Del, but only F2 took me to what I think is the BIOS editing menu.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xepxr.jpg)
The rest just took me straight to this
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U4FM.jpg)

As for my USB, I've used Disks to "restore partition image" on a Ubuntu 17.04 iso.

Thanks for helping me @heynnema. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It needs unallocated space *after* the partitions to be expanded. You need to move it to the left first.

Comment: @MichaelBay two things... 1) they can't resize or move whilst the partition is active, so they have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and 2) although I don't do it this way, you can resize to the left, into the unallocated space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot the a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on sda5 in the lower pane and select **move**
- **move** sda5 all the way left
- **resize** the right-side of sda5 all the way to the right
- if it all looks ok, click the Apply icon
- exit `gparted` and reboot

Comment: Thanks for answering. So you mean I have to boot from a USB containing ubuntu.iso, not gparted.iso right? I read somewhere that I'm supposed to boot live from USB but am not sure what that means.

Comment: @AnNguyen to boot a DVD or a USB, you turn on your computer and hit a function key (typically F12) to bring up a boot menu where you can select to boot the DVD or the USB.

Comment: @AnNguyen You can boot to either a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in `Try Ubuntu` mode and start `gparted`, or a gparted CD/DVD/USB and start `gparted`. **These should be current versions**. Either of these, that is, a DVD or a USB, can be created from a downloaded .iso file. A USB is sometimes called a flash drive, or a pen drive. I personally prefer doing this from a DVD, it's more reliable. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you earlier. So I am now in the boot menu. Should I turn 1st boot into ( usb hard disk)/ (usb CD/DVD) or (usb floppy) , another option is hard disk:ubuntu? And how do I know if I've successfully booted to a USB? One more thing, it now takes over 3 minutes to boot up my laptop whereas it only took about 10 sec before I tinkered with gparted...

Comment: You're not in the BIOS editing the boot order, are you? No, you shouldn't be there. Power cycle your computer, and watch the splash screen for a hint on what the function keys do... one function key will `enter the BIOS` and a different function key will `show boot menu`. You want to `show boot menu`, and there you should be able to select the USB flash drive (assuming it's already inserted). I don't know what tinkering you did in gparted before, so I can't tell you why it's booting slow now... what did you do?

Comment: I've edited my original post with photos of my screen. Please have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: @AnNguyen I'm unsure of where you stand. I don't understand "I've used Disks to "restore partition image" on a Ubuntu 17.04 iso". I've Googled "Lenovo boot menu" and the consensus seems to be the fn+F12 keys together should get you to the boot menu where you can select to boot to the USB flash drive. Then you can get to `gparted` and complete the instructions in my answer. If you've done that, please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful, thanks!